# How to list SO users who answer often and adequately

Tags: stackexchange-api

It has been 2 years since I started Python programming, and as with novice programmers I am often stuck with unanswered questions- frustrating exceptions in my projects, and I have not been able to get past that stage. Fortunately, some SO users exceed my expectations and give a very detailed answer. I want to find these awesome people hidden in SO!

So, inspired by a post in Quora, I would like to find Stackoverflow users that could potentially answer my questions.

Strategy:

- Find how many answers a user provided in tags `Python, Django,
  React, GIS, machine-learning`.
- How many of these answers were voted up.
- How many times a user answers questions per month.

### **Expected output:**

- A list of SO users ranked in order of how often they reply.

My question is how can I achieve that using stackexchange API?Thank you.

Comment: Try something and post it on:

https://ai.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That doesn't sound really like machine learning, not strategy nor output.

Comment: No web-scraping / no SO-API: no data to reason about. (i'm ignoring rules on web-scraping or what you want to do when you recognized these users)

Comment: I edited the question, removing machine learning.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I don't see the need for a code. The list of users can be obtained from the stackexchange API.
https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/top-answerers-on-tags